# on the corner office

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrases

I would like to know what is the meaning of *on the corner office* ?.Please help me to understand in this context.

David MacDonald, CEO of Softchoice, a Toronto-based business that helps companies with technology, is another ambitious executive, but he never had his sights `on the corner office`, he said.

Comment: [Corner office](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_office)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you split the sentence a little incorrectly there.

To understand the sentence, consider the phrases "had his sights on" and "the corner office".

To "have your sights on" something means to want it, especially with the intention to do something to get it.

A corner office is an office at the corner of a building floor -- meaning it gets at least two walls' worth of window space, making it a premium spot and thus something suitable for administrative members of an organization.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_office

Answer (score 1):

*Corner office* is a term that indicates **a top management position** within a company, and is therefore given ***to the senior most executives***, like CEO, CTO, CFO etc.

Read up about "[corner office](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_office)" here:

> A corner office is an office that is located in the corner of a
>   building. Corner offices are considered desirable because they have
>   windows on two exterior walls, as opposed to a typical office with
>   only one window or none at all (windowless offices occupying a corner
>   of a building are therefore not typically considered “corner
>   offices”). As corner offices are often given to the most senior
>   executives, the term primarily refers to top management positions,
>   such as the chief executive officer (CEO),[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_office) chief financial officer
>   (CFO), chief operating officer (COO), chief marketing officer (CMO),
>   chief information officer (CIO), General counsel (GC) and the director
>   of human resources. In organizations which do not use this corporate
>   hierarchy, such as law firms and political parties, the corner office
>   generally refers to the most senior partners or officials who are
>   involved with corporate governance.

In the example you've given, it means that even though David MacDonald (a CEO) is an ambitious executive, he is also *[down-to-earth](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=down%20to%20earth)* and doesn't want to acquire the top spot for himself.